# I'm trying to display 4 radio buttons on the left and 4 on the buttons on right and one radio button at botstom of the center

Tags: java, android

//this is the layout file i want to display 2 by 4 buttons on the top and at the button add one radio button enable and disable at the bottom center

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/CSettingsScreen"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_dirt"
android:keepScreenOn="true"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".CoachingSettings" >


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_coachingElement"
    android:layout_width="450dp"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.81"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/right_coachingElement"
    android:layout_width="450dp"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.71"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

//this radio button is enable or disable all 8 buttons and this should be at the bottom and in the center

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<RadioButton    
    android:id="@+id/enableAll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enable All" />    

<RadioButton    
    android:id="@+id/disableAll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Disable All" />
</RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please rewrite what you mean or provide a drawn picture of what you want. We cannot understand your problems from the one sentance you write .-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi try this code i hope it will help you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio0"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="RadioButton" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="RadioButton" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="RadioButton" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="RadioButton" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio0"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="RadioButton" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="RadioButton" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="RadioButton" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="RadioButton" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/enableAll"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enable All" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/disableAll"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Disable All" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thnaks exactly what i wanted

Comment: you are welcome any time